# Termination checking of simple uncurried functions

Tags: currying, agda, termination

The following recursive binary function over naturals is obviously terminating:

```
open import Data.Nat

curried : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
curried zero    k = k
curried (suc n) k = curried n (suc k)
```

and Agda accepts it as so.

However, the following uncurried version of the same function is also still obviously terminating, since the first coordinate of the pair is always peeling off a layer of `suc`, so the second coordinate shouldn't even matter:

```
open import Data.Product

uncurried : ℕ × ℕ → ℕ
uncurried (zero  , k) = k
uncurried (suc n , k) = uncurried (n , suc k)
```

Alas, the termination checker of Agda 2.6.2.2 rejects it:

```
Termination checking failed for the following functions:
  uncurried
Problematic calls:
  uncurried (n , suc k)
```

Is there a way (other than currying...) to push `uncurried` through the termination checker?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: See https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/995